# Redirect php product link to other page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect 
https://www.eurekahomehealthcare.com/eureka/services-details.php?id=34
to
https://www.eurekahomehealthcare.com/service/babysitting-services/

can anyone guide me on how to do this using htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this rule on top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/eureka\/services-details\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=34
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.eurekahomehealthcare.com/service/babysitting-services/? [L,R=301]
```